# How to prepend text in a comment containing fields?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have this VBA macro to prepend a tilde to the contents of comments, but it doesn't work since the comments contain fields. (The fields get converted to text). Can someone help?

```
Sub PrependTildeToComments()
     For Each comm In ActiveDocument.Comments
          comm.Range.Text = "~ " & comm.Range.Text
     Next comm
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub PrependTildeToComments()
     For Each comm In ActiveDocument.Comments
          comm.Range.InsertBefore "~ "
     Next comm
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! On a side note, what is a general way to append/prepend/manipulate text in the presence of fields?

Comment: @JohnDoe - since `.Text` is a string, anything that cannot be represented as a string will be converted to plain text, or simply lost. If you know that fields are present you can set the fields to show the field code. Otherwise, make use of Intellisense, the object browser, and online help to learn what methods are available to you, e.g. `InsertBefore`, `InsertAfter` etc.